# Number of ways to obtain $\sum \limits_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i= \frac{(n-1)n}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to count all the $(a_0, ..., a_{n-1})$, with $a_i \in \mathbb{N}$, so that $\sum \limits_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i= \frac{(n-1)n}{2}$.

I know there exists more than n! possibilities, but I would like to know a method on how to count them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the total as a number of identical objects to be divided among $n$ boxes (the "$a$"s). To divide we place $n-1$ dividers between the objects. Note that no two dividers can be in the same place because each $a$ is at least $1$. And you also know the number of places possible. So can you find the number of ways?

Comment: Actually some "a"s can be 0.

Comment: @Karavel: Then add one to each $a$ before applying the same solution. Of course the total would change accordingly.

Comment: I need to place $n$ dividers among $\frac{(n+1)n}{2}+n$ objects. That's it?

Comment: @Karavel: Yes, if you mean "place dividers at $(n-1)$ of $\frac{(n-1)n}{2}+n-1$ places" (not objects).

Comment: But if I place $\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$ dividers between $\frac{(n-1)n}{2}+n-1$, I can place two dividers next to each other, so I've already counted the a_i equal to 0. No? Do I really need to add 1 to each a?

Comment: @Karavel: Sorry I read your comment wrongly. It was incorrect. You have $n$ boxes and you only need $n-1$ dividers. I don't understand your last comment at all.

Comment: Well... I need to choose the place of n-1 dividers in $n-1+\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$ places. If I consider the a_i as a number of balls, I have $\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$ balls in a line and I choose where to place my n-1 dividers. If two dividers are next to each other, that means the corresponding a_i equal to 0. So the answer should be ${n-1+\frac{(n-1)n}{2}\choose n-1}$.

Comment: That's it or is there a fault?

Comment: @Karavel: Correct, and note that it is the same as Hanna's answer, though she didn't give any reason for her answer. (Your phrase in your previous comment, "next to", was ambiguous to me and could mean "touching", and you said "$\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$ dividers", which was why I couldn't really figure out what you meant.)

Comment: @Karavel: And I should add that it is good that you are looking at what the cases correspond to in the original problem. It is important to understand how the bijection works, and looking at boundary cases is always very helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! (and please excuse me for my poor english skills...)

Answer (score 1):

there are $\binom{n + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} -1}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ possibilities.